# Rails : Replace Attachment_fu DB with Paperclip S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip, attachment-fu

I replaced my attachment_fu with paperclip S3.
I am facing problem of transferring my old data which was in database tables to S3 buckets.
What would the best solution of doing these. Provide some solution on that.